# Price-set deletion question Civicrm 5.*

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Platform: WP 5.2, Civi 5.7 - UI seems not to allow deletion of price-sets - same behaviour in sandbox- create a price-set, add to an event; de-activate event, then try to delete price-set. No doubt this is due to the link table civicrm_price_set_entity which links price-set by id to a contribution/event. I would hesitate to go in to the DB and delete rows there, what is the 'right' way? Link table doesn't hold a status so one would need to remove rows w/event_id-price-set-id. I can see why, if the price-set was used for a sale, it'd be okay to disable but not delete but the 'some people' want to delete